# Warning: /etc/shadow has renamed /etc/shadow.newrpm

Tags: yum

After successful update of yum on my CentOS 6.4 VPS using command
        yum update -y
I got this message: Warning: /etc/shadow has renamed /etc/shadow.newrpm

Is it something wrong? Should I rename it? Please help. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong necessarily.  If yum updates configuration files, usually somewhere under /etc, it saves the pre-update file and tells you so that if there is something in the old file that needs to be copied/implemented in the new file, you'll have it.  It's a good idea to look for .rpmnew files on occassion to insure your files are appropriate for your configuration.